# can jquery/javascript be inside of form tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am hoping to embed a script inside of a form such as below, but it does not fire the event. I wanted to ask if this will ever work or if I am going to down a dead end.
Thank you

```
...
<form method="post">
 <fieldset>
 <input type="text" name="test" value="">
  <script>$(document).ready(function() {alert("document is ready");});</script>
 </fieldset>
</form>
...
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery BEFORE the inline script??

Comment: That works just fine. Can you give more details about what you were trying when it didn't work?

Comment: Why aren't you placing that in the head or end of the body? Placing JavaScript in the middle of a document is considered bad practice

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. You need to tell us the intended purpose of the code. If you have loaded jQuery, that piece of code can be anywhere in the page but I guess you do not intend to do what you show us here. If you want to know if the input field exist, you must not wrap it in document.ready

Comment: you could but there is not benefit of having it there or at the end of the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For script to be in  tags, it has to be either pure javascript or jquery needs to be included somewhere before. You could try something like this, and see if it works (pure js alternative to your js snippet):
...

```
 <script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      alert("Document is ready");
 });
 </script>
```

...

Comment: Thank you, jquery is added in the footer of the html, so it was in fact, unavailable at this location. As to why I am adding it here instead of the head or body, I am maintaining some existing, messy php and it will save me a lot of work to get this working. The pure js above is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.